# Time and Work :

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A can do as much work as C in 2 days and C does in 3 days as Much work as B in 4 days.what time B would require to do a work which A can finish in 16 Weeks?

I have tried:

I have calculated the Efficiency A:C as 1:2

and B:C as 3:4

Then I have calculated the overall efficiency as 4:6:8

A as 16 weeks B as When?

For that

```
16*6/4

I got 24 , but it wrong
```

**What I am doing Mistake Please anyone Guide me for the Answer**

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake.

B's 4 day work = $\frac 4B$

C's 3 day work = $\frac 3C$

And these are equal so,

$\frac 4B = \frac 3C$

$\frac BC = \frac 43$

Comment: ok I have Understand, then what is the answer

Comment: You are helping a lot, I have found out answer, can you put your own answer,I can check with you , you are helping me a lot

Comment: Yes the Answer is 128/3 ,My Answer

Comment: Yes your answer is correct. And I am fond of aptitude. So mine pleasure to help you.

Comment: Any doubt you have?